# Trees and path finding in Fortran

Tags: recursion, tree, fortran, nodes, fortran95

I am attempting to replicate some Python code in Fortran 90 to make it work within a larger Fortran project I am contributing to.  Specifically, I am trying to convert some code that recursively identifies upstream paths in a binary tree, such as in the following example:

```
     4 -- 5 -- 8
    / 
   2 --- 6 - 9 -- 10
  /           \ 
 1              -- 11
  \
   3 ----7
```

This tree is represented and traversed by:

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.parent = None
        self.children = set()
        self._upstream = set()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Node({})".format(self.name)

    # Recursively search upstream in the drainage network, returns a set of all paths
    @property
    def upstream_paths(self):
        if not self._paths:
            for child in self.children:
                if child.upstream_paths:
                    self._paths.extend([child] + path for path in child.upstream_paths)
                else:
                    self._paths.append([child])
        return self._paths

from collections import defaultdict

edges = {(11, 9), (10, 9), (9, 6), (6, 2), (8, 5), (5, 4), (4, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1), (7, 3)}
nodes = collections.defaultdict(lambda: Node())

for node, parent in edges:
    nodes[node].name = node
    nodes[parent].name = parent
    nodes[node].parent = nodes[parent]
    nodes[parent].children.add(nodes[node])
```

Is it possible to implement anything like this in Fortran 90? I have a decent understanding of recursion in f90 but without the object-orientedness of Python, I can't imagine how this can be done.

EDIT:

For further description:

What I intend to do is identify upstream drainage paths in a dendritic stream network. For any given outlet (root) there may be hundreds or thousands upstream paths. There would be no modification of the network required once it is initialized, although there will be calls to many different nodes within the network (in the above example, a call will be made for all upstream paths from 1, from 6, from 5, etc.)  I've been looking into using pointers but can't seem to find any examples out there of this kind of path-finding.

Comment: You have the tag fortran95, are you restricted to that, or would you also use newer features?

Comment: I could probably use newer features if that helps.

Comment: Well, depends on how you would like this to be implemented, it could be done solely with pointers, I think. Or you could work out some array structures. If you want to make use of objects, you could use the object oriented features added in F2003. The choice of data structure mainly depends on your preferences. Looking for performance? Does the result need to be accessed often, or rather modified more often. Stuff like this. In your way, your question is too broad for a good answer. The answer to wether it would be possible is just: yes...

Answer (score 3):

I find that it's much easier to convert Python towards another language while you're still in Python (and then you can test in Python every step of the way).  Python is so flexible that it is much easier to make Python that looks like F90 (or almost anything else) than the other way around.

I used to do this with assembly language.  I'd modify my python to make it look more like assembler, then try to code it in assembler, realize I'd missed something, then modify the Python again.  By the time I finished, I had Python and assembly language that were easy to read and had one-to-one correspondence, and *the Python had been tested* every step of the way.  The assembly language just worked(TM) when I ran it.

FWIW, if removing the recursion is something you are considering, [here](http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2013-05-11-recursive-to-iterative.html) is an excellent guide on the best way to do exactly that.